# An XSL select="child::node" issue

Tags: xslt, xpath

There is an issue that I can't understand and will be grateful for help:

I have an xml file that looks like this

```
<xml>
    <parent>
        <child_node>1</child_node>
        <child_node>2</child_node>
        <child_node>3</child_node>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child_node>4</child_node>
    </parent>
</xml>
```

And an xsl template:

```
<xsl:template name="template">
    <xsl:param name="top_node"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$top_node/child::child_node">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

which is called with `<xsl:with-param name="top_node" select="xml/parent">`

I expect this to return only the child nodes that are children of a single parent node, as it is shown [here](http://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/xsl/xsl/foil22.html), however it returns all the child nodes. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to figure out what the ultimate intent of this XSLT is without seeing more of it, but the reason you're getting this behavior is that the path `xml/parent` selects *all* nodes that match that path, not just the first one.  If you want to apply it to just the first one, you can do this:

```
<xsl:with-param name="top_node" select="xml/parent[1]">
```

If you want to apply it to a certain other one:

```
<xsl:with-param name="top_node" select="xml/parent[2]">
<xsl:with-param name="top_node" select="xml/parent[3]">
etc.
```